# Set negative margin on ImageView shifts ImageView but not Image

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I Need to shift an ImageView, which is a direct child of a LinearLayout, a bit to the left.

What happens: The View is shifted (can see the "bounding box" is shifted, with android layout manager) but the drawable keeps in the same place.

Also the drawable is cut on the right side, if I set margin low enough.

[image]

Why is this? Any advice?

- Clarification: I have to shift the Image to the left. That means a bit ouside of the bounds of the containing layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems elements are always clipped when they get outside of parent's bounds (also with clipChildren=false).

A solution is to create an additional container-layout for everything besides of the item to be shifted. And then shift the container-layout in the opposite direction.

For example, to shift -10dip:

```
<Original container ...>
    <Item to be shifted/>
    <New container with margin 10dip>
         <Previous content of Original container ... />
    </New container with margin 10dip>
</Original container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but would you please provide us an example with real codes? I couldn't get the idea. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Hi. Still needing it? Sorry no time... just put both the item you want to "shift" and the rest (in a containing layout) inside a relative or frame layout, and instead of shifting the item to the left, shift the "rest" to the rigt...

Answer (score 3):

If your container have enough padding you can set its **clipToPadding** to **false** and use negative margin!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using negative margin? use a positive a bit more to the opposite side of the ImageView to the direction you want to shift the image, i.e. if you want to shift the image to the left, use more positive margin to the right.

Comment: I have to shift the Image to the left. That means a bit ouside of the bounds of the containing layout.

Comment: Try using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the xml to auto adjust the bounds of the view.